# Damage effect costing some of your own life

Tags: powers, mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I am currently helping one of my players create a power where he "sacrifices" some of his life in exchange for dealing even more damage to an opponent. I thought it to be like the player has to pass the same resistance check as the opponent but with a +5 circumstance bonus. I just can't seem to find any power/modifier that would let me do that. I thought maybe a damage effect with a quirk would do the trick but I don't really understand them. Do you know how this might be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Side Effect](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/modifiers#TOC-SIDE-EFFECT--1-OR--2-COST-PER-RANK-)

> Failing to successfully use an effect with this flaw causes some problematic effect. Failure includes missing an attack check, or the target successfully resisting the effect. If the side effect always occurs when you use the effect, whether you succeed or fail, it is worth –2 cost per rank.
>
> The exact nature of the side effect is for you and the Gamemaster to determine. As a general guideline, it should be an effect about the same in value as the effect with this flaw. So an effect with a cost of 20 points should have a 20-point side effect. Typical side effects include Affliction, Damage, or Weaken, or the base effect itself (it essentially rebounds and affects you instead). The Side Effect does not require an attack check and only affects you, although the GM may permit some Side Effects with the Area modifier on a case-by-case basis. You get a normal resistance check against the Side Effect. If you are immune to your own powers, you aren’t immune to its side-effect.
>
> The GM may also allow a Complication Side Effect, which essentially imposes a complication on you without awarding a victory point. See Complications for more information.

Now this simply works as a regular attack with a Flaw. Transcending the damage/attack power level might be a different matter although one could consider using Extra Effort to boost the effect by +1 in exchange for a Hero Point if they didn't normally have this Flaw, or if they voluntarily failed the -1 Flaw.

Another option, albeit one that again requires a Hero Point to provide extra effect, is to use [Luck Control](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/effect-descriptions/luck-control-control) with the "force reroll" option. This [Anydice analysis](http://anydice.com/program/99c6) shows that it creates an average "roll" of 7.17 versus 9.5 for Extra Effort, and it skews the results to the lower side of rolls.

And, of course, as the GM, you can ultimately choose to do whatever the heck you want, Rule 0 and all, but that's how you might work within the stated rules.